# Put array values into different html textboxes

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-apps-script

I need to publish individuals' exam results from a google [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L1Qu6QCaDucr4Jy5eOAnQkX-wpYjz6eevqAMzBc72iQ/edit?usp=sharing). I have found some code and created another HTML page which now gives me the required result properly if I click the SHOW link. The app script is :

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L1Qu6QCaDucr4Jy5eOAnQkX-wpYjz6eevqAMzBc72iQ/edit#gid=0");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

function doGet(e){
 return search(e) ;
}  



function doPost(e){
 return search(e) ;
}  


   function search(e) {
  var id = e.parameter.id;

  var values = sheet
    .getDataRange()
    .getValues()
    .filter(function(row) {
      return row[0] == id;
    });

  var content = JSON.stringify(values);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(content).setMimeType(
    ContentService.MimeType.TEXT
  );
}
```

and the HTML is :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
<input type="text" id="txtName"/>
<a href = "javascript:;" onclick = "this.href='https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwu_DKPuOMMb26-TjuO4rUWxYvobzNpd4TsqehsGxW9D9DTOLvF/exec?id=' + document.getElementById('txtName').value">SHOW</a>
</body>
</html>
```

It gives the result in an array like [[ROLL, "Name", MARKS1, MARKS2, MARKS3...]]. Now I need to use these values at an HTML page like

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  
<h1>INSTITUTE NAME</h1>
Name <input type="text" id="name"/><br>
Roll <input type="text" id="roll"/><br>
Subject 1 <input type="text" id="sub1"/><br>
Subject 2 <input type="text" id="sub2"/><br>
Subject 3 <input type="text" id="sub3"/><br>
Subject 4 <input type="text" id="sub4"/><br>
Subject 5 <input type="text" id="sub5"/><br>

</body>
</html>
```

I mean like

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Every function must have a different name.  There appears to be two search functions.

Comment: Sorry! I mistakenly added the function twice. Edited now. I've not realized your second comment. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two HTML, you can do the entire process with one HTML using google.script.run [1] to communicate your code.gs with the Index.html, and update it with the data from the spreadsheet.

Just create an Index.html file with this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <input type="text" id="txtName"/>
  <button id="show">SHOW</button>
  <h1>INSTITUTE NAME</h1>
    Name <input type="text" id="name"/><br>
    Roll <input type="text" id="roll"/><br>
    Subject 1 <input type="text" id="sub1"/><br>
    Subject 2 <input type="text" id="sub2"/><br>
    Subject 3 <input type="text" id="sub3"/><br>
    Subject 4 <input type="text" id="sub4"/><br>
    Subject 5 <input type="text" id="sub5"/><br>
  </body>
<script>
//When click on show button it will run search function
window.onload = function(e){ 
  document.getElementById('show')
    .addEventListener('click', search);
}

//Get the value for txtName input and run search function in code.gs
function search() {
  var txtName = document.getElementById('txtName').value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fillInfo).withFailureHandler(function (e) { console.log(e) }).search(txtName);
}

//It will run when a success response comes from search function in code.gs and updates the input with the sheet info
function fillInfo(values) {
  document.getElementById('name').value = values[1];
  document.getElementById('roll').value = values[0];
  document.getElementById('sub1').value = values[2];
  document.getElementById('sub2').value = values[3];
  document.getElementById('sub3').value = values[4];
  document.getElementById('sub4').value = values[5];
  document.getElementById('sub5').value = values[6];
}
</script>
</html>
```

code.gs

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

//Search for the id and return the array for that row
function search(id) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L1Qu6QCaDucr4Jy5eOAnQkX-wpYjz6eevqAMzBc72iQ/edit#gid=0");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var values = sheet
  .getDataRange()
  .getValues()
  .filter(function(row) {
    return row[0] == id;
  });

   return values[0];
}
```

Deploy the application and you can access to it with the URL.

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication

Comment: It's just better than what I expected. Thanks a billion :D

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the results array is like the one you told. I think the best way to handle these is creating a dom node and appending to a container element and wrapping that logic to a looping function. Here's my example:

```
const resultElement = (value) => {
    let wrapper = document.createElement("div");

    //ROLL
    let rollElement = document.createElement("input");
    rollElement.setAttribute("type","text");
    rollElement.value = value[0];
    wrapper.appendChild(rollElement);

    //Name
    let nameElement = document.createElement("input");
    nameElement.setAttribute("type","text");
    nameElement.value = value[1];
    wrapper.appendChild(nameElement);

    //Marks
    for(let i = 2; i < value.length; i++) {
        let markElement = document.createElement("input");
        markElement.setAttribute("type","text");
        markElement.value = value[i];
        markElement.setAttribute("id", ("mark_"+i));
        wrapper.appendChild(markElement);
    }
    return wrapper;
}

const handleAllValues = (values) => {
    let container = document.getElementById("container");
    for(let i = 0;i<values.length;i++) {
        let el = resultElement(values[i]);
        container.appendChild(el);
    }
}
```

and you should have an element with `id="container"` in your html.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems a good suggestion. I have pested these in my code.gs but It is giving me a Syntex Error !!

Comment: I checked my code, it ran without any errors. Can you please check your code again, it might be caused by anything before or after that. I can check it too, if you share your code.

Comment: I don't know how to share code. Is it ok if I paste those here?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1i6hPAV6d76sObZ89R3M_fqkwgzvrQ1oyK_9tAmQ3vec/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @ImtiazSiddique You should call the `handleAllValues` function with the result of `search` function. Can you please call `handleAllValues` with returned array in onClick function. And don't forget to add a `<div id="container"></div>` element to your html.

Comment: Thanks dude. The approach by Andres Duarte is far better than mine so I following that. Thanks a lot for your much effort and time :)